# neo4j - export cypher scripts from localhost:7474 frontend - how to?

Tags: neo4j, export, cypher

neo4j cypher scripts export?

how can I export all my interactive cypher scripts 
from that fabulous localhost:7474 frontend?

thx

Answer (score 2):

Right now, please copy & paste them.

You can also go to the javascript console to the Resources tab where you find them in LocalStorage, for `http://localhost:7474/`

Javascript console meaning your browser (Chrome, Safari) developer console or Firebug in Firefox.

Comment: thanks a lot.

I have searched my whole harddisk but there is no
"neo4j-shell"

on my windows installation of neo4j.

It looks as if http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/shell-starting.html ignores Windows users?

Comment: ah, I see, it's only in the old environment "Classic UI Webadmin" ?

Comment: So I have found the 
"neo4j-sh" prompt ("power tool console"). What to do from here? Thanks!

Comment: updated the answer, you were looking for the wrong "console", sorry

Comment: Thanks a lot, Michael! I have now found the ... Firefox ... Menu ... Developer ... - but I don't know what to do there.  Then I installed Firebug Add-on- and I do not know where to look. Please guide me, thanks!

Comment: To solve the other riddle https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005693 I have deleted the firefox history. And *sigh* now all my code snippets are gone, too - of course, me stupid ;-)

Comment: feature request: Make an extra index / storage / node, under which all the interactive Cypher scripts (and everything else that is done in the browser) are stored, then I could do something like   "MATCH (n:Cypher) FROM DB.browser RETURN n" to access all my interactive snippets.

Answer (score 2):

I tried Evan extension but at the moment it doesn't work with the recently released version 3.2 of Neo4j.

After looking at how queries are saved in the local storage I put together a quick javascript function to run in the developer console that automatically prompts with a download message to save a txt file with all your queries in it.

#### Script:

```
(function() {
//get all the queries from the local storage
var allCypherQueries = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("neo4j.documents"));
var allQueryString = "";

// parses all the queries but the 19 prepackaged ones into a string
for (i=19; i < allCypherQueries.length; i++) {
    allQueryString += allCypherQueries[i].content + "\n\n";
};

// creates a DOM element to click to prompt a download, clicks it and removes it from the DOM
var element = document.createElement('a');
element.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([allQueryString], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8;"}));
element.download = 'queriesBackup.txt';  //you can change this string to the name you prefer

document.body.appendChild(element);
element.click();
document.body.removeChild(element);
})();
```

If you want to download only some of your queries, you have to manually change the indexes in the *for* cycle knowing that the first 19 queries are the default ones, then the array follows the folders order.

Notes:

- this was tested only with Neo4j 3.2
- this was tested in Firefox 53, Chrome 58 and Vivaldi 1.9

Comment: Thanks! The script is very useful! Now I needn't copy my query code by hand!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, where I wanted to share scripts with my team, so I put together a little Chrome extension that you can get [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/neo4j-exporter/nifbiilmebabmhiekpccmhjcenkkfbke/related?hl=en).

Basically, it adds an additional section underneath the import Cypher / Grass scripts box, which has an export button, a download button and a file drop box.

The export button produces files which can be dropped into the file drop box, the download button produces a more readable file, and dropping a file on the download box appends / updates the current favourites with the file contents.

Comment: It seems that the extension doesn't work now, there is no additional button or other things?

Comment: What version of Neo4j are you running?

Comment: neo4j:
Version: 3.4.7
Edition: Community
Chrome:
69.0.3497.100(64 bit)
Windows 7