# neo4j - localhost:7474 browser - which nodes are coloured? (py2neo)

Tags: colors, neo4j, nodes, py2neo

**neo4j - *localhost:7474 browser* - which nodes are coloured? (py2neo)**

I am creating a complex neo4j database with py2neo.
So far I have 6 node indices and labels, and 5 relationship indices and labels.

When I look through the *localhost:7474/browser* , some of my node type get coloured, some stay gray.

What is the trigger that colours the nodes in the *localhost:7474/browser* - or are there only 4 colours in the preset?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

There are 6 colors in total right now.

Nodes with a label get styled (colored), the other stay gray.

You can also choose the styling and color if you click on a node. In the popup menu on the "eye" tab you can also select the property to show as node-title, circle color & size.

If you open the `</> View Stylesheet` link at the bottom the browser brings up a stylesheet viewer with the GRASS (Graph-Style-Sheet) for your current visualization. Please try to reset it with the top-right fire extinguisher icon.

Btw. you can also style relationships, if you click on one the popup opens as well, and you can choose color and width per relationship-type.

I recorded a video too: https://vimeo.com/97204829

Enjoy!

See:

[image: neo4j browser visualization]

Comment: Thanks a lot.  

Inspired by your answer, I added  
graph_db.get_or_create_index(neo4j.Node, "myLabel1")  
and   
graph_db.get_or_create_index(neo4j.Relationship, "myLabel2")    
for all the nodes which were gray.   

Still no change.   
New DB, still gray.  
  
Then I deleted the whole firefox history - and voila: The nodes are coloured now.  Thanks!

Comment: Before, gray, they actually had labels assigned already, using batch.add_labels(c,"myLabel1"). But I had to delete the firefox history, only then they are coloured now.