# Standard nodecolors in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I was wondering if anybody could elaborate on the colors in Neo4j.
As far as i understood the Green color is when an node has a label, the grey without. But I couldnt find others, and I understood from this  [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24005693/neo4j-localhost7474-browser-which-nodes-are-coloured-py2neo) that there are 6. I tried the code below from the [documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#query-load-csv), and changed Person to Gene and Ontology respectively

The result is:
Green, Purple (but empty circle when viewed) and grey. How come? shouldnt all of them be the same color?

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "http://neo4j.com/docs/3.0.1/csv/import/persons.csv" AS csvLine
CREATE (p:Person { id: toInt(csvLine.id), name: csvLine.name })

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "http://neo4j.com/docs/3.0.1/csv/import/persons.csv" AS csvLine
CREATE (p:Gene { id: toInt(csvLine.id), name: csvLine.name })

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "http://neo4j.com/docs/3.0.1/csv/import/persons.csv" AS csvLine
CREATE (p:Ontology { id: toInt(csvLine.id), name: csvLine.name })
```

Comment: This is just a visual display thing, driven by a `.grass` template that you can download, edit, and upload.

Comment: okay, but shouldnt the three different node labels give the same color then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the colors yourself, see:

http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-neo4j-browser/

They are represented in a format called GRASS in your local browser storage, that can be synched to the cloud.

Comment: thanks, sorry. I had misunderstood it, thought the color was given to nodes with certain general attributes, not something you specified.